# SQLGroup-by subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery

I'm sure someone will spot right away what to me is puzzling, so thanks in advance. I have a subquery using a group-by on name and zipcode fields, filtering for group counts > 1. I get 528 groups. I want to see the individual full records, so I do an inner join to this result set on the name and zipcode fields. I expect to see at least 2 X 528 records resulting as a minimum since each subquery row represents at least two records. But I only get 190 rows and and can't figure out the flaw in my logic.

```
select m1.* 
from MasterList m1
join
(
    select FirstName, LastName, Zipcode, count(*) Cnt
        from MasterList m2
        group by FirstName, LastName,Zipcode
        having count(*) > 1
) x
on m1.FirstName = x.FirstName and
m1.LastName = x.LastName and
m1.Zipcode = x.Zipcode
```

I hope that is sufficient detail. I must not be understanding how the join is working. But I get the same result if I use filter conditions instead of join conditions.

Thanks again,
JimK

Comment: `each subquery row represents at least two records` is wrong. For each row in `m1` you have 0 or 1 row in `x`

Comment: Provide sample data, expected result and explanation of them and may be somebody help you to solve you task

Comment: What I meant was that for each row in x, there should be at least two rows in m1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any *NULL* first name, last name or zipcodes?  Sometimes it could mess up the results.  Without seeing any sample data, I cannot really help too much, but try doing following in your JOIN clause:

```
on isnull(m1.FirstNamem, '') = isnull(x.FirstName, '') and
isnull(m1.LastName, '') = isnull(x.LastName, '') and
isnull(m1.Zipcode, '') = isnull(x.Zipcode, '')
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have `NULL` values in one field.  In any case, window functions are a better approach:

```
select m.* 
from (select m.*, count(*) over (partition by FirstName, LastName, Zipcode) as cnt
      from MasterList m
     ) m
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Yes, this is a more elegant solution, certainly. How is it a "better" approach more pragmatically?

Comment: @user3091705 . . . Joining using a function is to be discouraged, because it can severely inhibit optimization.  This should perform faster, because SQL engines are optimized for window functions (the window function replaces both a `join` and a `group by`).  Plus, it automatically works for `NULL` values.